# There is a gap between elements and its eating my brains

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

Below are the two HTML elements the gap is between - **section and the footer**

```css
/* contact form */

#contact {
  min-height: 500px;
  height: auto;
}

#contact .contact-form {
  background: #93cb52;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

#contact .contact-form p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 1.3rem;
}

#contact .contact-form h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1.3rem;
}

#contact .contact-form .input {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0px;
}

#contact .contact-form label {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.i20 {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 20px;
}

.submit-btn {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background: #333;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}


/* footer */

#footer {
  height: 200px;
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#footer p {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Contact and Map -->
<section id="contact">
  <div class="contact-form">
    <h1>Contact Us</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae, perspiciatis?</p>
    <div class="input">
      <label for="name"> Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="i20" placeholder="Enter Name">

      <label for="email"> Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="i20" placeholder="Enter Name">

      <label for="phone-number"> Phone number</label>
      <input type="text" class="i20" placeholder="Enter Name">

      <label for="Message"> Message</label>
      <input type="text" class="i20" placeholder="Enter Name">

      <a href="#" class="submit-btn">Submit</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="map"></div>

</section>


<!-- footer -->
<section id="footer">
  <p>Copyright &copy; Sahara Equity, All Rights Reserved</p>
</section>
```

I am using HTML5 and CSS3. Would appreciate also any suggestions to make this code a little less redundant and compact. New learner here.

This is what the current page looks like. Need there to be 0 whitespace.

[image: website image]

Comment: `min-height: 500px;` is causing the issue, the form takes up les that `500px` and the rest of the space is just left there

Comment: its still the same after removing min-height

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes from the default margin of the paragraph element. Just set its `margin-top` to `0` then the gap will disappear.

```css
/* contact form */

#contact {
  min-height: 500px;
  height: auto;
}

#contact .contact-form {
  background: #93cb52;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

#contact .contact-form p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 1.3rem;
}

#contact .contact-form h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1.3rem;
}

#contact .contact-form .input {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0px;
}

#contact .contact-form label {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.i20 {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 20px;
}

.submit-btn {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background: #333;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}


/* footer */

#footer {
  height: 200px;
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#footer p {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Contact and Map -->
<section id="contact">
  <div class="contact-form">
    <h1>Contact Us</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae, perspiciatis?</p>
    <div class="input">
      <label for="name"> Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="i20" placeholder="Enter Name">

      <label for="email"> Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="i20" placeholder="Enter Name">

      <label for="phone-number"> Phone number</label>
      <input type="text" class="i20" placeholder="Enter Name">

      <label for="Message"> Message</label>
      <input type="text" class="i20" placeholder="Enter Name">

      <a href="#" class="submit-btn">Submit</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="map"></div>

</section>


<!-- footer -->
<section id="footer">
  <p>Copyright &copy; Sahara Equity, All Rights Reserved</p>
</section>
```

That behavior is called [Collapsing margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add reset css at the top of the css file.
You can use below code as well but adding reset css code is a better way

```
*{
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use css reset
https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

or just

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```